# Can't upload file on linux server

Tags: php, linux, file, upload

I want to upload a file on a linux server but it doesnt work. In local it works perfectly but in server not. I dont know what is wrong. Even when I try to echo in the compare.php it doesnt show anything.

upload code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $bdd = DB::getInstance();
    $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT refCustomer, legalCompanyName FROM PV1.Client order by Client.legalCompanyName');
    $donnees = $reponse->fetch();
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="compare.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>
        <label for="client">Veuillez choisir le fournisseur :</label><br />
           <select name="client" id="client">
            <?php
            echo '<option value=""/></option>';
            while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch()){
                    echo '<option value='.$donnees['refCustomer'].'>'.$donnees['legalCompanyName'].' </option>';                               
            }
            $reponse->closeCursor();
            ?>
           </select>
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3145728" />
        <input type="file" name="monfichier" />
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="envoyer" value="Envoyer" class="myButton"/>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
```

and compare.php

```
$dossier = '';
echo "test";

if(isset($_POST['client'])){
$cin = $_POST['client'];
if(!empty(basename($_FILES['monfichier']['name']))){
    $file = basename($_FILES['monfichier']['name']);
    echo is_writable($file). "</br>";
    $taille_maxi = 3145728;
    $taille = filesize($_FILES['monfichier']['tmp_name']);
    $extensions = array('.xls', '.xlsx');
    $extension = strrchr($_FILES['monfichier']['name'], '.');
    //Début des vérifications de sécurité...
    if(!in_array($extension, $extensions)){
         $erreur = 'Vous devez uploader un fichier de type .xls';
    }

    if($taille>$taille_maxi){
         $erreur = 'Le fichier est trop gros...';
    }


    $rateSheet=NULL;
    if($extension == ".xls"){
        $rateSheet = Parser::parserXls($dosser.$file);
    }else{
        echo "Veuillez uploader un fichier Excel";
    }

...
```

Comment: Give 777 permission to your folder

Comment: already have all permission

Comment: blank screen can mean syntax errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: have you checked if the $_FILES variable is being filled. What does var_dump($_FILES) output. Also check the php.ini it could be an issue with max_upload_size settings.

Comment: I inserted the code     <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);    still nothing and the max_upload_size is 8m so its ok and upload_file is on in php.ini

Comment: Thats right I have a blank screan. And there is nothing when I right click to see the code source

Comment: whats the HTTP return code for the request ?

Comment: Ok in mod prod I can't see the php errors right? Sorry im new to programming. So how can I see in prod if I have errors because  error_reporting(E_ALL); doesnt work. (I work on my website which is already hosted)

Comment: Did you restart apache2 (or whatever webserver you're using) after updating the ini?